# CSS version of target attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xml

Is there a css-version of the target attribute like , instead of writing

```
<a href="example.php" target="something">Link</a>
```

i could have wrote :

```
<style type="text/css">
a { target:something; }
</style>
```

Comment: No, there is not! And why would a stylesheet be able to set an attribute ?

Answer (score 2):

**No, there isn't.**

Firstly, `target` is an HTML attribute, not a CSS style property. CSS cannot modify or create a new  attribute. You can, however, style all `a` elements that have target attributes with the selector:

```
a[target] {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't for the moment**, but there was a working draft by the W3C called [CSS3 Hyperlink Presentation Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks), now abandoned. It defines a CSS property named `target` which is meant to substitute the HTML attribute, and actually is way more specific and allows to do more than the old HTML `target`. Unfortunately, as fas as I know, no browser tried to implement it, I think that's the cause of abandonment. However, in the future could be proposed again (I hope, at least).

Comment: The answer is correct and useful, but the statement “it’s still a draft” is an understatement: the working draft is dated 24 February 2004, i.e. almost ten years ago. This means that it has effectively been abandoned; in fact, the [W3C page on CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) lists it under “Abandoned”. But this shows that you can’t do such things in CSS (if you could, they would not have tried to define anything like this).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated - there is not a way to do this with CSS *yet*.

A way ***to do*** this is with jQuery+css.

If you have given all of your links a specific class, use this jQuery to set the target, and if you want to set the target for ALL links, use the second set of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('a').hasClass('CLASSNAME')) {
        $(this).attr("target", "TARGET");
    }

}
```

If no class is set and you want all of the links on your page (that aren't internal links) to have a set target, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[href^=http]:not([href^=http://YOURSITEURLWITHWWW],[href^=http://YOURSITEURLWITHOUTWWW])')
    .add('a[href^=www]:not([href^=YOURSITEURLWITHWWW])')
        .attr('target','_blank');

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include jQuery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`